# Разница в показателях задействованных ресурсов

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, xubuntu, elementary-os

Проблема в следующем:
Из интереса решил ознакомиться с elementary OS и загрузился с live usb. Для просмотра данных о задействованных ресурсах использовал Task Manager и Gnome System Monitor... и вот в чем дело - при пустом рабочем столе первый выдает примерно 700 занятых мб. ram, а второй 1,8 гб. В чем тут секрет и кому верить? Примерно то же самое было, когда загружался с lubuntu

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скорее всего, разница - это освобождаемые кэш/буферы, которые в данный момент используются, однако при необходимости будут предоставлены новым процессам и являются условно-свободными